# Create iOS 7-style blur on UITableView's cells

Tags: uitableview, ios7, blur, gaussian

I have been able to create a blur on UIView by using this library:
https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView

which is pretty good and works and I have tried the same on UITableView but it does not work.
Does any one have any other ideas?

EDIT:

I was able to get it working with FXBlurView, just had to play around with layers

Comment: try this link https://github.com/youknowone/UI7Kit

Comment: good library but they dont support blur

Comment: did u find solution for it?

Comment: @PK86 yes you just have to play around with different layers, for example see Scott's answer below set clear background color and then set backgroundview to FXBlur View

Answer (score 2):

Here is a surprisingly elegant solution. Use `UIToolBar` which automatically comes with blur effect on background view (live). Simply set this as `backgroundview` of cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        // Do all your other stuff for setting up this cell.

        // Set the background view of the cell as UIToolbar for iOS 7 where it's translucent, picking up background view effect with blur.
        UIToolbar *translucentView = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

        cell.backgroundView = translucentView;
        //[translucentView release]; // If you are using retain/release for memory management(non-ARC).
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what do you mean by "lags tableview". If you doubt over solution, I assure you that I had tried it in a sample project on tableview and it did work fine.

Comment: Lags means = lagging, when scrolling

Comment: Don't make it in cellForRow but in the init of the cell to prevent lags.

Answer (score 1):

Set the FXBlurView as the `backgroundView` property of `tableView`.

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.backgroundView = blurView;
```